# Kotlin can't access items in fragment twice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

[image: Pic One]

I just create a simple app. I have MainActivity, FragmentOne and FragmentTwo. In picture you can see I can go FragmentOne and FragmentTwo anytime. And with "Update Textview" button I can change textview in fragmentOne. Example when I start the app, I just go fragmentone and go two and go again to one etc... And when I am in FragmentOne, I click to update button and the textview changes. There is no problem. And I go to FragmentTwo and come back FragmentOne and try to press Update button again, nothing changes.

In brief you can see in picture the textview "FRAGMENT ONE CREATED", I can change it for once, i can't change again. I didn't change Fragment's codes. This is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    goFragmentOne.setOnClickListener {
        val myAction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        myAction.replace(R.id.myFrameLayout,FragmentOne()).commit()
    }
    goFragmentTwo.setOnClickListener {
        val myAction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        myAction.replace(R.id.myFrameLayout,FragmentTwo()).commit()
    }
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {
        textViewOne.text = "UPDATED"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my MainActivity XML:

```
<FrameLayout> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goFragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO FRAGMENT ONE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goFragmentTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO FRAGMENT TWO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPDATE TEXTVIEW"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goFragmentOne"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnUpdate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please add fragment code.

Comment: You probably changing the textview in onCreate method.

Comment: I didn't any change in Fragments. OnCreate has just this: "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)". I just edited MainActivity

Comment: You want to change the textview which is inside Fragment from the activity. Better way is to change the Fragment views from inside fragment.

Comment: Make a function inside Fragment who will be responsible for changing its views.
Inside activity please use the following code to call function inside fragment.
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG)
fragment.functionHere();

Comment: You sure about this code? I got errors @WajahatHussain

Comment: This is a just a template, you need to change it according to your classes.

Answer (score 3):

You are capturing the old text view inside the activity. Once the fragments are replaced and recreted the old view object is not there anymore. what you see on the screen is a new text view with a new reference but the value you captured on the OnClick lambda doesn't match that new value. Try getting the view from the fragments with something like

```kotlin
currentlyLoadedFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.theTextViewID) // or similar
```

Comment: I'm new at Kotlin so what should i write to "currentlyLoadedFragment"?

Comment: When you make the fragment transaction, keep last placed the fragment in a local variable of your activity and name the variable `var currentlyLoadedFragment: Fragment? = null` so you can use it on the onClick method. Note that before putting any fragment inside the activity you won't have a fragment to set the text to

Answer (score 1):

You should split your code a bit more. The way you have it now is bad practice. "Actions" for FragmentA -> your btnUpdate should be only in FragmentA, since it is only for your FragmentA.
Using single activity architecture, you should put in your MainActivity onCreate only this

```
/*
You implement interfaces from FragmentA, and FragmentB 
( interface Callbacks{....} that were written in FragmentA and FragmentB )
 and then Android Studio will require you to implement methods defined in 
those interfaces (methods are goToFragmentA() and goToFragmentB()
*/
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentA.Callbacks, FragmentB.Callbacks {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//your starting layout, will put fragmentA as your starting layout if your fragment container is empty
        val currentFragmentOnScreen = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myFrameLayout)
        if (currentFragmentOnScreen == null) {
            val fragment = FragmentA()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.myFrameLayout, fragment)
                .commit()
        }
    }

//calls your function from FragmentB and goes to FragmentA on button click
   override fun goToFragmentA(){
      val fragment = FragmentA()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.myFrameLayout, fragment)
            .commit()
   }

//calls your function from FragmentA and goes to FragmentB on button click
   override fun goToFragmentB(){
      val fragment = FragmentB()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.myFrameLayout, fragment)
            .commit()
   }
```

then in your FragmentA()

```
class FragmentA() : Fragment() {
   ...
   interface Callbacks {
      fun goToFragmentB()
   }
   ...
   private var callbacks: Callbacks? = null
   ...
   override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as Callbacks?
    }
   ...
   override fun onStart() {
      ...
      btn.OnClickListener{
         callbacks?.goToFragmentB()
      }
      btnText.OnClickListener{
         textViewOne.text = "UPDATED"
      ...
   }
   ...
   override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        callbacks = null
    }
   ...
```

And FragmentB

```
class FragmentB() : Fragment() {
   ...
   interface Callbacks {
      fun goToFragmentA()
   }
   ...
   private var callbacks: Callbacks? = null
   ...
   override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as Callbacks?
    }
   ...
   override fun onStart() {
      ...
      btn.OnClickListener{
         callbacks?.goToFragmentA()
      }
      ...
   }
   ...
   override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        callbacks = null
    }
   ...
```

Comment: Yeah I can do this but there is no way for my problem? Like what if i create a timer in MainActivity for change textView every second. If i use timer in fragment, timer works only when fragment displays. So i want to change from my activity.

Answer (score -3):

Okay i write this code and worked:

```
 btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {
        val tv = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myFrameLayout)?.view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewOne)
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.text = "UPDATED"
        }
    }
```

Thank you for helping me guys!